# Overlay image to persp plot in R

Tags: r, gis

I'm trying to overlay an image (rasterstack or anything else) to a 3d persp plot of a dem (rasterlayer) in R.

Currently, this is what i have after a little code working

[image]

Which is basically:

```
persp(dem,theta=-35,col='white',scale=FALSE,box=FALSE,phi=25)
```

Now i want to overlay a satellite image to give it the aspect of a 3D real view. Something like this:

[image]

I dont know if this is possible, other than that i was thinking of just coloring each cell of the dem plot with the corresponding color of the satellite image, but again, i'm not sure how to do it.

Any suggerence is welcome!

Comment: `trans3d` can kind of do that, but it's built for points. You could theoretically do it per-pixel, but I'm sure there's a more practical raster method.

Comment: Yeah, i figured out a method using facets, but it's no time efficient, there must be a way..